# iOS - Best solution for image storage and fast downloads?

Tags: ios, firebase, alamofire

I'm looking into making an app involving users being able to upload photos, and then other users can see those photos (think like Instagram as an example).

I've used Firebase storage in another app before for storing user profile pictures, but I could never get the download speeds to work right. There was always a very noticeable delay.

Would I be best served looking into something else like AlamoFire for faster downloads? Or is there any way to speed up firebase storage?

A very general overview of what I'd be doing -- I'd have a collection view with thumbnails of all the user's images (which hopefully wouldn't take long to download since they'd be thumbnails), and then when the user taps on a cell it goes to a new view with the image full sized. I'm more worried about the image being loaded quickly enough on being tapped.

Comment: First thing; your question will probably be closed as "Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or *primarily opinion-based* may be put on hold by the community until they are improved." That being said have you looked into [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) as that's exactly what it's built for; "Cloud Storage is built for app developers who need to store and serve user-generated content, such as photos or videos"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two very mature and widely used alternatives to Firebase for image downloading and caching are [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and [PINCache](https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache).

However, it's very unlikely that excessive slowness is related to the image storage SDK that you choose. More details follow...

### Factors affecting mobile download speeds

The client-side storage solution should really have marginal effect on overall image download speeds. We're talking millisecond differences... if you see large multi-second differences between downloading with Firebase's client vs AFNetworking or NSURLSession, then you're likely doing something wrong.

You didn't specify what "slow" is (5 seconds? 50 seconds?) or if the issue was wifi or cellular.

The primary driver of slow downloads on mobile devices are:

- **Network type** (LTE, 4G, 3G, etc) are all relatively high latency compared to wifi and this will not vary from one network client to another.
- **Speed/capacity of the server** you're downloading from.
- **Number of concurrent downloads** you're attempting at once. For example if you download an image for every table view cell and the user is scrolling fast, your downloads will get very, very slow.
- **The device** you're benchmarking on. An iPhone X can be expected to download more and faster than an iPhone 6.

### Establishing a baseline download speed

I would start off by establishing the baseline for downloading your images. You can do this by connecting your laptop to a fast wifi and executing:

```
$ time curl <image url here> 1>/dev/null
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 20166  100 20166    0     0  73851      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 73868
curl  > /dev/null  0.02s user 0.01s system 11% cpu 0.297 total
```

This image can be expected to take 0.297s. Then in your app, time your downloads and see how they stack up. For on device benchmarking, you can try downloading directly using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty much convinced, that sql database is not proper place for storing large BLOB data. The better and reasonable place to store file is File System. I'd recommend to store photo files in dedicated application user directory and store the link in Firebase DB.

The choose of network framework is the matter of personal preferences, it doesn't affect downloading speed. All they are just a wrapper of foundation NSURLConnection